# How to get and edit Google calendar event? Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-calendar-api, google-api-client

I have this code :

```
client = Google::APIClient.new

oauth_yaml = YAML.load_file('lib/.google-api.yaml')
client = Google::APIClient.new
client.authorization.client_id = oauth_yaml["client_id"]
client.authorization.client_secret = oauth_yaml["client_secret"]
client.authorization.scope = oauth_yaml["scope"]
client.authorization.refresh_token = oauth_yaml["refresh_token"]
client.authorization.access_token = oauth_yaml["access_token"]

if client.authorization.refresh_token && client.authorization.expired?
  client.authorization.fetch_access_token!
end

service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')

result = client.execute(:api_method => service.settings.list)
```

and it's working :) But, can someone give me an example or a link to show me :) **How can I get user's events and update them?**

```
rails -v
Rails 3.2.13

ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

my Gemfile:

```
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'googlecalendar'
gem 'gdata'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'logger'
gem 'gdata_19'
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this [gem](https://github.com/northworld/google_calendar) and it worked fine.

But it doesn't use Google API, just log in with Gmail account and password and parse its response.

So I wonder this gem is good for you. Anyway, try it.

Comment: Thank you mate :)
Yup, it's good:) But I was told to go with other one -> https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/  :) Cuz, customers doesn't want to input mail & pass :)